# Square brackets with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I wish to create a `[` and `]` bracket just with CSS. Is there a way to specify the top and bottom border (Without slicing the image) so it looks like a bracket?

```
.bracket {
  border-top:20px;
  border-bottom:20px;
  border-right:none;
  border-left: 1px solid black; 
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just use `[` and `]`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```css
.b:after {
  content: "]"
}

.b:before {
  content: "["
}
```

```html
<span class="b">text</span>
```

working example: http://codepen.io/yardenst/pen/bhGIy

Comment: @YardenST cool solution, could I use this to add brackets to wrap images of different sizes as well?

Comment: @amanda and the brackets should be at the height of the image?

Comment: @YardenST that is correct they should inherit height of the image

Comment: @AmandaSky :after and :before as for now, are not supported on img tags. there are things that can be done, but it requires another question :)

Comment: ::after and ::before is the new syntax (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

Answer (score 16):

You can draw square brackets without the use of any pseudo elements in pure css.

**Steps:**

- Create an element like `<div>` or `<span>` and make it an `inline-block` so that its length becomes dependent on its content i.e length of this element will be as long as content inside it.
- Apply left / right borders.
- Use `linear-gradient()` to create 4 background images with specific `width` / `height` and draw on each corner of the box with `background-position`. The height factor of `background-size` should be equal to `border-left-width`.

**Necessary CSS:**

```
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ffb1bb, #ffb1bb),
                    linear-gradient(#ffb1bb, #ffb1bb),
                    linear-gradient(#ffb1bb, #ffb1bb),
                    linear-gradient(#ffb1bb, #ffb1bb);

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 8px 3px;
                    // ^^^ This value should be equal to width of left OR right border.
  background-position: top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right;

  border: solid #ffb1bb;
  border-width: 0 3px;
}
```

**Useful Resources:**

- Linear Gradient: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient), [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#linear-gradients).
- Background Image: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image), [W3](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-image).

**Output Image:**

[image: Output Image:]

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(white, silver);
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.widget-title {
  font: 20px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ffb1bb, #ffb1bb),
    linear-gradient(#ffb1bb, #ffb1bb),
    linear-gradient(#ffb1bb, #ffb1bb),
    linear-gradient(#ffb1bb, #ffb1bb);
  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 8px 3px;
  background-position: top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right;

  border: solid #ffb1bb;
  text-align: justify;
  border-width: 0 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="widget-title widgettitle">WHAT’S NEW</h4>

<h4 class="widget-title widgettitle">This is some dummy and multiline text and nothing meaning in this sentence,This is some dummy and multiline text and nothing meaning in this sentence,This is some dummy and multiline text and nothing meaning in this sentence...</h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :after and :sbefore pseudo-elements, with the content property.

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/content)

Something like

```
.bracket:after { content: ']' }
.bracket:before { content: '[' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you can do this instead:
HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="stick"></div>
        <div class="empty"></div>
        <div class="stick"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Div content</div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="stick"></div>
        <div class="empty"></div>
        <div class="stick"></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FF0000;
    border-top: 2px solid #FF0000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}
.stick{
    border-left: 2px solid #FF0000;
    height: 33%;
}
.empty{
    height: 34%;
}
.content{ float: left }
.left{ float: left; height: 100%; }
.right{ float: right; height: 100%; }
.clear{ clear: both }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8g4F/

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by usage of container's :before and :after pseudo elements.
Sass code:

```
$container-selector: h1;
$bg-color: white;
$bracket-color: orange;
$bracket-width: 10px;
$bracket-length: 30px;
// just reset
body {
  background-color: $bg-color;
}

// not really related
$container-selector {
  padding: 0 30px;
}

$container-selector {
  position: relative;
  border: $bracket-width solid $bracket-color;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -$bracket-width;
    right: $bracket-length - $bracket-width;
    left: $bracket-length - $bracket-width;
    height: $bracket-width;
    background-color: $bg-color;
  }
  &:after {
    top: initial;
    bottom: -$bracket-width;
  }
}
```

Working example is available here: https://jsfiddle.net/1uuodzdw/