# Fixed string but alternating template literal on an interval

Tags: javascript

I want to add brackets to a players score, but when updating on an interval it's also appending both string brackets multiple times instead of once.

```
setInterval(() => {
    for(let i in topmass){
       topmass[i].innerText = "[" + topmass[i].textContent + "]"
    } 
}, 100)
```

Name: *[score]*
**not:**
Name: *[[[[[[score]]]]]]*

Comment: can you provide more details , what's the purpose of writing the code inside for loop and inside setInterval ?

Comment: to update the score, but i don't want want there to be multiple brackets per score.

Comment: Why use an interval if topmass[i].textContent does not change? Also don't use for..in for an array. Can you post more code so we can figure out why you would use an interval?

Comment: Lastly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651022/square-brackets-with-css

Comment: Using the DOM to store state leads to some pretty hard to maintain code. I think you should look at storing what ever is in topmass[i].textContent in a data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each time you do this you  add [] to

```
 topmass[i].innerText = "[" + topmass[i].textContent + "]"
```

you change  to [dont forget to check null]

```
 topmass[i].innerText = "[" + topmass[i].textContent.match('[0-9,a-z]+')[0] + "]"
```

Comment: I think this is an X/Y problem. It would be great to know why he even adds brackets in an interval

Comment: @mplungjan Alternative if you  have less elements in tompass like less than 10 thenyou could do somethimng like 

     <span>[<span /><div class ='topmass'>SCORE<div/><span>]<span />

you  may not need to do anything with [] ...but if you are constrained with html OR if you have >10 elements and dont want a messy dom then first one is ok

Comment: that's way easier, thanks for that snipet! @mplungjan

Answer (score -1):

Well, maybe this will help.

Instead of extracting the score always from textContent, you can maintain another member inside each topmass element(say score). After every interval, you can update the score and
innerText accordingly.

```
setInterval(() => {
    // Update or initialize score, e.g. topmass[i].score += 10
    for(let i in topmass){
       topmass[i].innerText = "[" + topmass[i].score + "]"
    } 
}, 100)
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using [custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992115/custom-attributes-yea-or-nay)

Comment: That is completely different. And I don't disagree with that. But here we're making use of Javascript's power as a programming language, not defying HTML 5's standard. What we're doing has no relation with HTML tags, but with javascript objects.

Comment: `Tompass[i]` is a node in the DOM. You are adding a score custom attribute to each of the nodes.